# Exportar dados do informix

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, importação, informix

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com base nos dados de um ERP. Este ERP usa o banco INFORMIX cujo padrão de exportação de arquivos é DELIMITADO POR PIPES E SEM QUALIFICAÇÃO DE TEXTO.

Preciso importar os dados do Informix para o MySQL, mas precisa ter todos os campos delimitados por aspas duplas e separados por ponto vírgula.

Para importar para o INFORMIX eu sei como definir os delimitadores

```
LOAD FROM report/novoplan.csv DELIMITER ";" INSERT INTO ctplano
```

Mas não faço idéia de como definir a estrutura desejada no arquivo de saída